# Control while loop by Promise then function

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a function that returns Promise

```
let processWork = function () {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log('- internal: start')
    // just wait 200ms for example
    let future = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 200)
    while (future > new Date()) {}
    console.log('- internal: done')
    resolve()
  })
}
```

I call it and use `then` function to change variable to break endless while but not work

```
let doing = false
let done = false
while (!done) {
  if (doing) {
    continue
  }

  console.log('Starting work')
  doing = true
  processWork()
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Finished')
      done = true
    })
}
```

I get output

```
Starting work
- internal: start
- internal: done
```

and my code's still running forever.
My question is why `then function` not running in this case.

Comment: You're getting stuck in an infinite loop with `while (!done) if (doing) continue`. It never progresses beyond that once `doing` is `true`.

Comment: I'd imagine if something fails in the promise, it'll be returned as rejected into the `.catch()` block. Also it's possible nothing gets returned because your while block doesn't use the `.getTime()` method as you did in the future declaration.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of this, but could the while !done and continue be causing the main thread to never have a chance to call the .then function? Could to much work on the main thread prevent a Promise.then from being called?

Comment: What is purpose of `let doing = false
let done = false
while (!done) {
  if (doing) {
    continue
  }`? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @guest271314 I just try how Promise works. I use doing to call Promise one time.

Comment: @W.Scott, and deceze, thanks, I put doing check in while condition and It works

Comment: Don't ever do `while (future > new Date())` - this locks up the browser until the loop finishes. If you need a delay do it asynchronously with `setTimeout()`.

Comment: How is `while` loop related to `Promise`?

Comment: @LeNhatAnh Yes, that's *not* how promises work. What are you actually trying to do? `processWork().then(() => { console.log('Finished') })` is all you need.

Comment: @Bergi yes, this is way I do first, and I try something fun

Comment: But what you tried doesn't work. If you want to have fun with promises, use `async`/`await`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not true that a promise will somehow get resolved while a busy loop is being executed. As long as a loop is executing no other JavaScript will execute (excluding web workers). The following loop will *always* execute the `continue` statement in every iteration and will never finish.

```
let doing = false
let done = false
while (!done) {
  if (doing) {
    continue
  }
  // ...
}
```

No promise could help interrupt this loop, but in your case, there is not even a promise since *processWork* never gets executed.

If *processWork* would get executed, the loop in the promise constructor callback will lock up the browser until the target time arrives: no other JavaScript gets executed during that delay. This defeats the purpose of promises: they are intended *not* to lock up the browser and allow the execution of other code while the promise is still pending.

So, do it like this:

```js
let processWork = function () {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        console.log('- internal: start delay of 200ms')
        // just wait 200ms for example, but don't stop execution of other code
        setTimeout(resolve, 200);
    })
}

console.log('Starting work')
processWork().then(() => {
    console.log('Promise resolved. Finished');
});
console.log('Waiting for promise to resolve...');
console.log('In the meanwhile let\'s calculate 10!');
let fact = 1;
for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    fact *= i;
}
console.log('10! = ', fact);
```